# Sum of two dice rolls in java

Tags: java, dice

So I have a dice rolling program that seems to work so far, but the only problem I can't figure out is how to sum the outputs of the rolls. It rolls the dice again while summing the previous roll.

Here is the Die class I started with

```
public class Die{   //only thing changed was removing implementation of the interface

private int noFaces;

public Die() {
    noFaces = 6;
}

public int getNoFaces() {       //getter
    return noFaces;
}

public Die(int noFaces) {       //setter, sets new value according to passed parameter
    this.noFaces = noFaces;
}

public int roll() {             //generates random number+1 within specified "noFaces" range
    return (int) (Math.random() * noFaces + 1);
}

public void printRoll() {       //goes to above method roll() and prints the returned value
    System.out.println(roll());
}
```

}

and making one Die into a PairOfDice, which is where I'm having the summation issue

```
public class PairOfDice {

private Die d1, d2;

public PairOfDice() {       //initializes 2 die objects
    d1 = new Die();
    d2 = new Die();
}

public PairOfDice(int noFaces) {    //sets the dice equally
    d1 = new Die(noFaces);
    d2 = new Die(noFaces);
}   

public PairOfDice(int noFaces1, int noFaces2) { //sets dice separately
    d1 = new Die(noFaces1);
    d2 = new Die(noFaces2);
}

public void printRoll() {   //prints rolls
    System.out.println("Die 1 returned: " + d1.roll());
    System.out.println("Die 2 returned: " + d2.roll());

}

public void printRollSum(){     //print sum of both rolls
    System.out.println("Sum of both dice rolls are: " + (d1.roll() + d2.roll()));
}
```

}

and where I'm getting the output, RollingDice

```
public class RollingDice {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    PairOfDice pairOne = new PairOfDice();
    pairOne.printRollSum();
    System.out.println();

    PairOfDice pairTwo = new PairOfDice(10);
    pairTwo.printRoll();
    pairTwo.printRollSum();
    System.out.println();

    PairOfDice pairThree = new PairOfDice(100, 3);
    pairThree.printRoll();
    pairThree.printRollSum();

}
```

}

All help on either my program or the comments is appreciated, I'm still learning. Thanks!

Comment: So you want `printRoll()` and `printRollSum()` to use the same numbers, is that the issue? If so you need to store the result of the rolls b/c every roll will generate a new random number.

Comment: Every time `roll()` is called a new number is generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution, you could store the last rolled value in your `Die` class, (similar to `noFaces`, but call it `lastValue` for example), and then change printRollSum() to use `getLastValue()` instead of `roll()`

Comment: thanks, I added a
'public int getPrintRoll(){
  int i = roll();
  System.out.println(i);
  return i;
 }' to my Die.java class

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the sum of the two dice, but you're rolling the dice each time. `printRoll()` rolls and displays the values, then `printRollSum()` rolls them again, giving you different values.

Answer (score 0):

The method `roll()` will generate a new random number each time it is called so when you call `printRoll()` and  `printRollSum()` you will receive new numbers each time.

You need to store the results of `roll` in one of your classes and then provide a method to access those results.

Answer (score 0):

It generates new numbers every time `printRoll` and `printRollSum` are called. You should combine the two methods, or at least store the current value of the roll in a die, and access them through `printRollSum`

Answer (score 0):

Each of your printRoll() and printRollSum() calls is *re-rolling* the dice.  If you're looking to roll the dice, print each individual die's face value, then print the sum of those two face values, you'll need to store the results of the rolls and then perform the sum computation on those results.  For example:

```
public class PairOfDice {

private Die d1, d2;
int lastRollD1;
int lastRollD2;

public PairOfDice() {       //initializes 2 die objects
    d1 = new Die();
    d2 = new Die();
}

public PairOfDice(int noFaces) {    //sets the dice equally
    d1 = new Die(noFaces);
    d2 = new Die(noFaces);
}   

public PairOfDice(int noFaces1, int noFaces2) { //sets dice separately
    d1 = new Die(noFaces1);
    d2 = new Die(noFaces2);
}

public void roll()
{
    lastRollD1 = d1.roll();
    lastRollD2 = d2.roll();
}

public void printRoll() {   //prints rolls
    System.out.println("Die 1 returned: " + lastRollD1);
    System.out.println("Die 2 returned: " + lastRollD1);

}

public void printRollSum(){     //print sum of both rolls
    System.out.println("Sum of both dice rolls are: " + (lastRollD1 + lastRollD1));
}

}
```

In this version, your RollingDice would then call:

```
pairOne.roll();
pairOne.printRoll();
pairOne.printRollSum();
```